# Which is the correct way to conditionally enqueue a CSS file?

Tags: php, css, query, errors, wp-enqueue-style

`get_queried_object` returns `NULL` inside a function hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook when going to an nonexistent category URL on my website. If the category exists, the error is not shown and I think it does not exist.

I need it to conditionally load a CSS file for better modularization, not in the admin area but for the end-user.

What is the correct way to do this?

The error shown in the HTML:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'term_id' of non-object in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/custom-theme/functions.php on line 193

The code starting at line 193:

```php
if (get_queried_object()->term_id === 3 ||
        (count(get_the_category()) > 0 && get_the_category()[0]->slug == 'arta')) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwenty-style-2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style-arta.css', array(), $theme_version );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I agreed with [@PatJ](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/16121/pat-j) — you should check if [`get_queried_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) returns an object or not.

But you could *simplify* your code by simply using [`is_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) and [`in_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/) which are [conditional tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/#a-category-page) in WordPress:

```php
if ( is_category( 3 ) || in_category( 'arta' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwenty-style-2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style-arta.css', array(), $theme_version );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, `get_queried_object()` is a wrapper for [`WP_Query::get_queried_object()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/get_queried_object/), which will return `null` if there's no such object.

A simple way to check that you've got a non-null return is using [`empty()`](https://php.net/empty):

```
$object = get_queried_object();
if ( 
    ! empty( $object) &&
    ( 
        $object->term_id === 3 ||
        (
            count( get_the_category() ) > 0 &&
            get_the_category()[0]->slug == 'arta'
        )
    ) 
) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwenty-style-2', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style-arta.css', array(), $theme_version );
}
```

Comment: This misses the problem. The issue is not that `get_queried_object()` is missing. The issue is that when they are not viewing term archives then `get_queried_object()` is not returning `WP_Term`, meaning that `get_queried_object()->term_id` doesn't exist, even though `get_queried_object()` is not empty.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't sufficiently clear. My logic was this: The PHP notice says `Trying to get property 'term_id' of non-object`. `get_queried_object()` will return an object (`WP_Term`, `WP_Post`, `WP_Post_Type`, or `WP_User`) or `null`. I assumed that, given the options, OP is getting back the `null` value. `empty( NULL )` will be `true`.